# iOS 12 equivalent of JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.withoutEscapingSlashes (Swift)?

Tags: json, swift, request, escaping, json-serialization

My code:

```
let json: [String: Any] = ...
request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .withoutEscapingSlashes)
```

The problem is it works in iOS 13 only but I need to support iOS 12 too.

How to fix it correctly? Should I convert `Data` to `String`, replace "\/" with "/" and convert to `Data` back manually each time?